# What is the right way to architect this concurrency issue? Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am building a very simple game using Spring Boot. One of the features  that the game requires is to be able to handle multiple games concurrently.

So in my controller, I have these methods.

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class GameController {

private final GameService gameService;

@Autowired
 public GameController(final GameService gameService) {
 this.gameService = gameService;
 }

@RequestMapping("/createGame")
@ResponseBody
public String createGameController(@RequestParam(value = 
"playerName") final List<String> playerNames) {
 final String gameId = gameService.createGameAndGenerateGameId(playerNames);
 return "Your gameId is = " + gameId + " \n Give this to other users to  
 challenge!";
  }
```

So this method above is solely responsible for creating a game and returning a 'gameId'  which is unique for every game. What I would like to happen for every REQUEST there should be a new gameId being returned. What is currently happening is that every request is 'sharing' the same gameId.

I understand this can be solved by implementing new Thread manually for every request but is there a spring way to do this?

```
@RequestMapping("/startGame")
@ResponseBody
 public String startGameController(@RequestParam(value = 
 "gameId") 
 final String gameId) {
    return gameService.startGame(gameId);
 }
```

Another feature. So when I user want to perform an action in a game they have a specific gameID for their designated game. Now,  if there are multiple threads which contain separate games. How do I map a specific gameId to the specific game in a thread?

Example:

There are 3 games running on three different threads.

Game 1/Thread 1: id=123

Game 2/Thread 2: id=321

Game 3/Thread 3: id=213

Client 1 sends /startGame?gameId=321

How do designate client 1 request to Game 2/Thread 2? Does spring have a functionality for this or does this have to be done without spring?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'm not sure how you imagine the workflow from there on tbh... but I guess I'd leave it to the GameService to do this mapping?

Comment: @daniu I thought about that too. However I was wondering if spring had anything from the controller side to handle request/thread management.

Comment: _What is currently happening is that every request is 'sharing' the same gameId._ Do you mean request or response? And if every response give the same gameId, maybe your service is incorrect.

Comment: As Partrick said if you are seeing same gameId in the response then something is not correct in the gameservice, your SQL is not correct at the backend. For second part, as Game2 is created with gameId as 321 for client1, so whenever you are sending any request to spring for client1 then always send gameId=321 in the request then all processing will happen in backend for this client and gameId-321

Comment: @Amit K Bist Okay so I assume the service has to handle actions like this. My question is now does spring have any features that handles this?  So for example if I pass a request with gameId from the controller to service can spring automatically map to the right thread/game  if there are multiple games happening?  Or is this something I have to do manually.

Answer (score 0):

Every request by default is executed in a separate thread. I assume that for each new game you create game id by incrementing the counter. To make it thread safe use `AtomicLong` or instead of numeric IDs create UUIDs.

Regarding second part, there is nothing like this built in. Why does every game need to run in a separate thread?